# Is the same htm source edit extension available on windows?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for the chrome extension that allows you to edit html source and instantly view the result. See the screenshot  [for mac](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/463/6c14329610118e53d06046b.png), perhaps there is no such software available for windows version of chrome, but I would appreciate the mac version reference too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm terribly sorry, this is NOT a chrome plugin, but node.js application https://github.com/phuu and this is really good one [see the screen](http://postimg.org/image/8opj7vpcz/)

Answer (score 0):

There is already this kind of tool built in to Chrome. If you right click on HTML page and select "Inspect Element" you can make your changes and Chrome will update itself automaticly.

If you don't like this feature however and want one that looks beter, check out this link. I'm almost certain there will be some results that you like.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-apps/Editor

Comment: sorry, but I know that chrome can edit html source and I've been using at least 3 extensions from the link you provided, but all of them aren't even close to the mac extension from the screenshot.